# Playwright: TypeError: Cannot read property 'retry' of undefined

Tags: playwright

I'm currently in the process of writing tests in Playwright.

What I notice is a strange output in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'retry' of undefined
```

Even though all the tests pass, I get this, and it leads to ugly additional output:

[image: screenshot]

Here is the content of the `debug.log`:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/josua/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.4/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/josua/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.4/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test:run'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest:run', 'test:run', 'posttest:run' ]
5 info lifecycle adg-components@0.0.0~pretest:run: adg-components@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle adg-components@0.0.0~test:run: adg-components@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle adg-components@0.0.0~test:run: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle adg-components@0.0.0~test:run: PATH: /Users/josua/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/josua/Projects/adg-components-ramon/node_modules/.bin:/Users/josua/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.10/bin:/Users/josua/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.10@global/bin:/Users/josua/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.10/bin:/Users/josua/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Users/josua/.rvm/bin
9 verbose lifecycle adg-components@0.0.0~test:run: CWD: /Users/josua/Projects/adg-components-ramon
10 silly lifecycle adg-components@0.0.0~test:run: Args: [ '-c', 'playwright test' ]
11 silly lifecycle adg-components@0.0.0~test:run: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle adg-components@0.0.0~test:run: Failed to exec test:run script
13 verbose stack Error: adg-components@0.0.0 test:run: `playwright test`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/josua/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/josua/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid adg-components@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/josua/Projects/adg-components-ramon
16 verbose Darwin 21.2.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/josua/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.4/bin/node" "/Users/josua/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.4/bin/npm" "run" "test:run"
18 verbose node v12.18.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error adg-components@0.0.0 test:run: `playwright test`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the adg-components@0.0.0 test:run script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Can't find any reference to `retry` in there though. And in my whole project, looking for `retry`, I only find this:

[image: screenshot2]

What confuses me most is that it only happens with several tests: when I attach `.only` to a `test`, for some it happens, for some it doesn't. Couldn't find a difference between those tests though: I even copy&pasted the content of some test from a non-failing one to a failing one (replace the failing one), and it still failed. Very strange.

Comment: Maybe it is related to this, but we will not know if you don't define it. In playwright config you have option retry:
"retries:" The maximum number of retry attempts per test.
On other hand not sure this is mandatory config. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#testing-options

Comment: Meanwhile, the problem miraculously just disappeared. No idea when and why exactly. Will keep you posted if it returns.

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused by having two tests of the same name when one of them is set as test.only

It seem there is an issue opened for this in playwright.
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/14034